# Dashboard Contact Form

Tags: forms, dashboard, contact

Is there a way to make a dashboard contact form widget?

I just simply want to have it there so users can give feedback directly from their dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can do this by [adding a dashboard widget](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_add_dashboard_widget) with a contact form function that uses AJAX to submit the form.

```
function myplugin_dashboard_widget() {
    ajax_contact_form();
}

function myplugin_add_dashboard_widgets() {
    wp_add_dashboard_widget('myplugin_contact_widget', 'My Plugin Contact Form', 'myplugin_dashboard_widget');
}

add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'myplugin_add_dashboard_widgets' );
```

Answer (score 0):

This plugin might be what you're looking for:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/surveypress/